# How to make OnControllerColliderHit method to detect collision only once?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision

**OnControllerColliderHit** method detects collision every frame. I want it to be called *only once* when I touch another object with collider.

Here is an example of what I have right now. Look at collision counter down below: https://youtu.be/-2t45tkWTc8

I want **OnControllerColliderHit** method to be like **OnCollisionEnter**.

My CollisionDetection script:

```
public class SphereCollisionHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    private int collisionCounter;

    [SerializeField] private GameObject gameObj;
    private TMP_Text textMesh;

    void Start ()
    {
        textMesh = gameObj.GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
    }

    void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
    {
        if (hit.gameObject.tag == "Cube")
        {
            collisionCounter = collisionCounter + 1;
            textMesh.text = collisionCounter.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I've already tried to use **OnCollisionEnter**, but it works bad with a *Player Object* that has CharacterController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API [`OnControllerColliderHit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnControllerColliderHit.html) indeed sounds like it makes sense that this is called every frame while moving.

> This can be used to push objects when they collide with the character.

---

If you want to get it **only once in total** simply add a flag

```
private bool alreadyHit;
```

and then do

```
void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
{
    if(alreadyHit) return;

    if (hit.gameObject.CompareTag("Cube"))
    {
        alreadyHit = true;

        collisionCounter = collisionCounter + 1;
        textMesh.text = collisionCounter.ToString();
    }
}
```

---

Or if your goal is rather tracking every hit with **each object** once you could use something like

```
private readonly HashSet<GameObject> alreadyCollidedWith = new HashSet<GameObject>();
```

and then

```
void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
{
    if (hit.gameObject.CompareTag("Cube") && !alreadyCollidedWith.Contains(hit.gameObject))
    {
        alreadyCollidedWith.Add(hit.gameObject);

        collisionCounter = collisionCounter + 1;
        textMesh.text = collisionCounter.ToString();
    }
}
```